# FireBase DataBase android получение ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-database

Ребят,такой вопрос. Как мне получить ID элемента (он имеет примерно такой вид - Kc4nRY0LcszcMSYwK1C) в БД генерируемой при создании самой FireBase.

В документации к fb нашел такой способ

```
userRoomName = editName.getText().toString();
                        ChatRoom newRoom = new ChatRoom(userRoomName);
                        mDatabaseReference.child(CHILD_THREE).push().setValue(newRoom);

                        final String[] mkey = new String[1];
                        mDatabaseReference.child(CHILD_THREE)
                                .child(userRoomName).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    mkey[0] = postSnapshot.getKey();

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
```

Дальше я так понял в моем mkey[0] и лежит этот уникальный id, но там пусто.

Comment: Ваш ключ лежит вот тут: `mDatabaseReference.child(CHILD_THREE).push()`

Comment: я так понимаю,что таким образом я получаю все ключи всех элементов в этом каталоге?! а как мне получить ключ конкретного элемента?

Comment: Нет, так вы должны получить тот самый ID новосозданного элемента

Comment: да, вы правы,все получил, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить ID новосозданного элемента надо вызвать `mDatabaseReference.child(CHILD_THREE).push()` - этот метод как раз и создаёт новый уникальный ключ

Answer (score 0):

Сначало получаешь id, после вставляешь при добавлении данных. Можно ещё в колбэке получать, но он работает только в онлайн режиме. Мой способ подходит всегда.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference logsRef = database.getReference(id);
String activeIdLog = logsRef.push().getKey();
logsRef.child(activeIdLog).setValue(model);
```